# Is there an equivalence relation of which the quotient topology is homeomorphic to codomain of a quotient map?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X,Y$ be topological spaces.

Let $p:X\rightarrow Y$ be a quotient map.

Then, does there exist an equivalence relation $\sim$ on $X$ such that $X/\sim$ is homeomorphic to $Y$?

Comment: It seems offhand to me that the obvious choice is that $a\sim b$ if and only if $p(a) = p(b)$.  Clearly this $~$ is an equivalence relation; whether you have $X/\sim\  \equiv Y$ remains to be worked out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In other words: does every quotient arise as a quotient of an equivalence relation?

yes, take the equivalence relation generated by $a \sim b $ if they have the same image in $Y$. Then the map $p: X \to Y$ factors through the quotient $X/\sim$ and also the quotient map $X \to X/\sim$ factors through $Y$.