# Why is this map homeomorphism?

Tags: general-topology

Munkres - Topology p.143

Let $p:X\rightarrow Y$ be a quotient map.

Set $x\sim y$ iff $p(x)=p(y)$.

Let $X/\sim$ be the quotient space of $X$ with respect to $\sim$.

Let $\pi:X\rightarrow X/\sim$ be the projection map.

Then, there exists a bijective quotient map $\phi:X/\sim\rightarrow Y$ such that $\phi\circ \pi = p$.

Why is this $\phi$ a homeomorphism?

Comment: Closely related question from the same user: [Is there an equivalence relation of which the quotient topology is homeomorphic to codomain of a quotient map?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/966744/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A bijective quotient map $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is always a homeomorphism.

A quotient map is always continuous (suppose $O \subset Y$ is open, then by definition of a quotient map, $O$ is open in $Y$ iff $f^{-1}[O]$ is open in $X$, so the left to right implication shows that $f$ is continuous).

Also, if $O \subset X$ is open, because $f$ is a bijection, $O = f^{-1}[f[O]]$.
Again by the above definition of a quotient topology, $f[O]$ is open in $Y$ (as its inverse image under $f$ equals $O$ again, which is open!), so $f$ is an open map. But this is equivalent to the inverse map $f^{-1}$ (which exists, as $f$ is a bijection) is continuous.

So as soon as you have checked that your $\phi$ is bijective and a quotient map, you're done.